# Is blockchain an invention or discovery?

Tags: blockchain

I think the society has been working on the concept of blockchain inherently. 
e.g. Consider the scenario where wholesale seller and retailer are interacting. Retailer asks wholesale seller for pink colour cloth. When wholesale seller delivers, retailer doesn't accept it is pink. He just calls some people to tell the correct colour. This the argument is settled.

Each person's brain is a distributed ledger.

Comment: This sounds like a great topic to discuss at a meetup or on reddit, but not a great fit here. We're more concerned with topics that can be answered conclusively.